# want to change gridoption preselectedRows row in angular slickgrid dynamically on button click (function check);

Tags: javascript, angular, slickgrid

when the button clicked some secific row are selected using preselected grid option in angular slickgrid but if I do so gridoption preseletedrow is change but it did not show. please help me

**ts file**

```
 arr1 = [1,2,8];    
 arr =[];

ngOnInit() {   
    this.onPageLoad();   
   this.dataset = [];   
  }  
 onPageLoad(){    
    this.gridOptions = {    
      enableAutoResize: true,       // true by default    
      enableCellNavigation: true,    
      enableFiltering: true,        
      editable: true,    
      rowSelectionOptions: {    
        selectActiveRow: false,    
      },    
      preselectedRows:this.arr,    
      enableCheckboxSelector: true,    
      enableRowSelection: true,   
      };   
  }      
check(){    
   this.gridOptions.preselectedRows =this.arr;    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any of the grid options starting with the `pre` prefix (`presets`, `preselectedRows`, ...) should be used only when building the grid (on first page load). To dynamically change row selection you will need to use other functions of SlickGrid, there are 2 ways of doing it and both of them are very similar.

Also as a reminder, [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) is a wrapper on top of SlickGrid which is the core library and to select some row(s), you will need to call the a method from the core library.

You first need to get the `AngularGridInstance` and from there you can call the `setSelectedRows` method from the `GridService` (which exposes some methods of SlickGrid) or use it directly from the SlickGrid core library.

```html
<!-- Component View -->
<angular-slickgrid 
  gridId="grid4" 
  [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions" 
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [dataset]="dataset" 
  (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)"> <!-- <<== you need this line !-->
</angular-slickgrid>
```

```
// Component
export class MyComponent {
  angularGrid: AngularGridInstance;
  columnDefinitions: Column[];
  gridOptions: GridOption;
  dataset: any[];

  // as the name suggest, this instance will be available 
  // once the grid finished rendering and is ready
  angularGridReady(angularGrid: AngularGridInstance) {
    this.angularGrid = angularGrid;
  }

  changeSelectionDynamically(rowIds: number[]) {
    if (this.angularGrid) {
      // you can call the method from the GridService
      // I prefer to use this because it has the Types (TypeScript)
      angularGrid.gridService.setSelectedRows(rowIndexes);

      // OR call the method from the SlickGrid object (core lib instance)
      angularGrid.slickGrid.setSelectedRows(rowIndexes);
    }
  }
```

So from the sample shown, which one should I choose? It's really up to you, you can use one or the other and the result will be the same. The only reason I've copied over some of the methods into the `GridService` is simply because `Angular-Slickgrid` is written in TypeScript and so we have the Type checkes, while SlickGrid (core library) is written in plain JavaScript and it won't complain if you made an error.

Lastly if you wish to clear your selections before calling a new set of selections, you can do so by calling an empty array, like shown below. You have to do this if you had any selection prior to your new selection.

```
angularGrid.slickGrid.setSelectedRows([]);     // first clear the selection
angularGrid.slickGrid.setSelectedRows(rowIndexes); // then set a new selection
```

EDIT

To dynamically Select All Rows cannot be done in 1 execution since the Row Selection Plugin doesn't have any methods to do that. However what would probably work would be to get the IDs of all your rows (through a `map`) from the DataView.

```
// actually this won't work since setSelectedRows() is grid row indexed
// so item IDs won't work, so don't use this
const allRowIds = angularGrid.dataView.getItems().map(item => item.id);
angularGrid.slickGrid.setSelectedRows(allRowIds);
```

NOTE

That actually won't work, I just remembered that `setSelectedRows` uses grid row indexes, not item IDs. However what you could do is get the `dataset` length and fill an array with theses indexes.

```
const allRowIndexes = Array.from(Array(this.dataset.length).keys());
angularGrid.slickGrid.setSelectedRows(allRowIndexes);
```

Also note that I'm the author of [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) and for more info about this answer, you can read up this [SlickGrid & DataView objects](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/SlickGrid-&-DataView-Objects) Wiki. I wrote a lot of Wikis and your question is actually answered in yet another way in this [Row Selection](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Row-Selection#mixing-single--multiple-row-selections) Wiki.

Comment: yes i try it but some row checkbox are selected not the full row .and cant get those data also...

Comment: I don't think there's a way to call a Select All Rows dynamically. What you can maybe do is call a `map` on all rows from the DataView, something like this `const allRowIds = angularGrid.dataView.getItems().map(item => item.id)` then call the `setSelectedRows(allRowIds)`. That is the only way I see this being possible

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear enough, every time that I think I understand your question, you seem to change it again. So unless you provide more specific question, I won't answer anymore. However, I just remember that `setSelectedRows` is by grid row indexes, not by item ID, so keep that in mind. Lastly to get the item data object, you just have to search for it, there are plenty of answers on how to do that on Stack Overflow, you can also use the `GridService` to get that info, you just need to search a bit